# Submitting a ViewModel Derived Form in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: forms, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I want to create a form that is comprised of fields that come from separate models and then, when submitted, updates the corresponding tables in the database.

I couldn't find the answer anywhere so I tinkered with things until I made something work. Being new to all of this, however, I doubt the efficacy of my solution. I'm hoping that by stating my problem and showing my solution you can better understand what I need and be able to help me find the best solution for my problem.

I like simple, abstract examples so here is what I currently have working:

First, I make a Color Model...

```
namespace example.Models
{
    public class Color
    {
        public int ColorID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I make a Shape Model...

```
namespace example.Models
{
    public class Shape
    {
        public int ShapeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next, I make a simple ViewModel...

```
namespace example.ViewModels
{
    public class ColorAndShapeViewModel
    {
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public Shape Shape { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my DbContext...

```
namespace example.DAL
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next, the Controller...

```
namespace example.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private MyContext db = new MyContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ColorAndShapeViewModel viewmodel)
        {
            Color newColor = new Color();
            newColor.Name = viewmodel.Color.Name;

            Shape newShape = new Shape();
            newShape.Name = viewmodel.Shape.Name;

            db.Colors.Add(newColor);
            db.Shapes.Add(newShape);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

Lastly, the View...

```
@model example.ViewModels.ColorAndShapeViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Color.Name)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Color.Name)<br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shape.Name)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Shape.Name)<br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Thus far, everything works as expected: I am able to enter data for separate models into a single form and submit it. The database is updated (the color goes into the color table, the shape into the shape table) and all is well—or is it? In reality, I will have a much longer form using several models which are related to each other. My present solution would require a large controller, full of `newObject.Property = viewModel.Object.Property` statements. Isn't that undesirable? Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could do your mapping outside of your controller (for readability) and /or use a mapping library (look at AutoMapper, ValueInjecter...)

Comment: Mapping elsewhere would be better, yes, so I'll do that if I don't find a better, more efficient way of doing this. What I'm hoping is to find out that somehow it's possible to do something like `SaveChanges()` on the ViewModel itself and avoid needing to manually map everything. (As for AutoMapper et al., I prefer to learn how things are done before I use shortcuts so I'll keep those in mind for later.)

Comment: What you have in your example is pretty close to textbook MVC tutorials.  This is the basic way that it is handled.  You can, as suggested above, add a separate class or layer to handle mappings, or use a third party tool. But really, this question would be a better fit on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as there isn't really any problem here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Forty-Two and thanks for letting me know about the Code Review area. Had I known of it, I definitely would have posted this "looking for a better answer" question there. Thanks again!